# Ruby. Интерполяция строк Хешом

Tags: строки, ruby, интерполяция

Есть пример форматной строки:

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (%<system[ua_platform].to_s>s;"
```

И несколько хешей, данные из которых надо вставить по разным ключам в строку.
Например, `system`, который может хранить под разными ключами `nil`.
Как сделать так, чтоб не передавать для каждого ключа в строке нужные ему данные, т.к. их очень много и они могут меняться, как и сама строка, а передать один хеш и все заработало.

Например, в `Python` можно сделать так:

```py
"({system[ua_platform]}; rv:{app[build_version]})".format(system=system, app=app)
```

Где `system` и `app` - словари.

К примеру `app`:

```rb
app = {
      'name' => 'Netscape',
      'product_sub' => '20100101',
      'vendor' => '',
      'build_version' => '45.0',
      'build_id' => '',
      'gecko_trail' => '20100101'
    }
```

Comment: Аналогом строки на питоне в руби будет `"(#{system[ua_platform]}; rv: #{app[build_version]})"`. Вроде ничего сложного, так что может быть я неверно поняла вопрос?

Comment: @Василиса эта строка не сразу интерполируется, в моем случае всегда возникает `KeyError`:
`key<system[ua_platform].to_s> not found (KeyError)`. `ua_template % {system: sys, app: app}`. `ua_template` - это форматная строка.

Comment: Ага, чувствую, что невнимательно вопрос прочла. Увы, но format string не умеют такое, насколько я понимаю. А что мешает обычную интерполяцию использовать, которая умеет?

Comment: @Василиса потому что строк много и программа сама выбирает какую использовать в конкретном случае

Comment: Может быть, добавите больше исходных данных в вопрос. Так-то вроде бы ничего не мешает выбирать и использовать строки вида `"Mozilla/5.0 (#{system[ua_platform]};"`

Comment: @Василиса если их интерполировать не сразу, возникнет исключение, что передано 0 ключей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно обернуть строку с интерполяцией в proc и вызывать тогда, когда есть все нужные данные

```
string = proc { |system| "Mozilla/5.0 #{system[ua_platform]}"}
system = { win: 'Windows', mac: 'MacOS' }
ua_platform = :mac

string.call(system)
=> "Mozilla/5.0 MacOS"
```